# Pages: Different table cell padding left/right vs. top/bottom

Tags: pages

I often need to use tables as layout helpers in Pages. Unfortunately, there's a feature which I really, really miss: Often I'd need to adjust the horizontal cell padding separately from the vertical cell padding:

[image: PagesTableCellPadding]

Obviously, Pages seems to only have a single padding input for all sides (**Format → Text → Layout → Text Inset**). Is there a workaround or trick to adjust the padding in a more “expert” manner?

**Edit:** What seemed to work **only on first** sight, was to use the “border” instead and assign a X pt large white line above and below the table row as shown below. This looked good, however when exporting or printing the document, Pages obviously mis-calculates some bounding boxes and and descenders e.g. from “g” will be cut off :-(

[image: Hack1]

Comment: I made it work with a custom height (Arrange | Size | Height)

Comment: @FabienSa I assume, this would break auto-sizing the cells, though?

Comment: It seems to work, not sure why...